# React lib overriding your web app context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I was wondering about good patterns concerning the react context.

Let's get a public library, for example `react-intl` that exposes a Provider (IntlProvider).
Let's create a library `barLib` that uses `react-intl` to manage translations internally and that also exposes a `Provider`.
Now let's imagine I create a web app and use both `barLib` and `react-intl`.

I don't expect the `barLib` to ever override my react-intl context, because i'm not aware it uses internally the `react-intl` lib.
But the `barLib` can accidentally override the react-intl context => https://codesandbox.io/s/embedded-contexts-test-z8e7b

This kinda breaks the isolation of libs IMO.

I see several solutions :

- Don't use an other lib context in the `barLib` (pretty extreme)
- Check that there is not already an intl context in the `barLib`, if so merge the context values ?

I'm not convinced with either solutions, what do you guys think about it ?

Answer (score 0):

After giving some more thoughts about this. I think you should mark the `react-intl` library as a peer dependency in the `barLib` and document the fact that to use the barLib, you need to wrap it in a `react-intl` context.

In conclusion, if you want to use a context in your library, just make it a peer dependency and don't put the Provider in it